# Is Api Result the same as the frontend result?

Tags: php, api, frontend, query-builder, shopware

In my code I am trying to get access my data bank through query builder, everything works I am able to get access to everything as a `string` (which this is what I want), everything but my date is returned as a `class DateTime object` in my Frontend, the intersting part for me through Api I am getting my date as a `string` and not as a `class DateTime object` and I cant understand why I am getting two different results when I am using the same methods same `query builder` and my Question is why am I getting two different results? is it possible to get different result through Api? and if so why? and is there a way to convert the `class DateTime object` to a `string`?

**Api Controller**

```
public function indexAction()
    {

        $request = $this->Request();
        $limit = $request->getParam('limit', 1000);
        $offset = $request->getParam('start', 0);
        $sort = $request->getParam('sort', []);
        $filter = $request->getParam('filter', []);

        $result = $this->resource->getList($offset, $limit, $filter, $sort);

        $view = $this->View();
        $view->assign($result);
        $view->assign('success', true);
    }
```

**Fronend Controller**

```
public function listAction()
{
    $feedback= $this->resource->getList(0, 10, null, null);

    $this->View()->assign('feedback', $feedback);

}
```

**QueryBuilder**

```
protected function getBaseQuery()
{
    $builder = $this->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $builder->select(['feedback', 'user_id.firstname','user_id.lastname',])
        ->from(FeedbackModel::class, 'feedback')
        ->leftJoin('feedback.customer', 'user_id');
    return $builder;
}
```

**getList function**

```
public function getList($offset, $limit, $filter, $sort)
{
    $this->checkPrivilege('read');
    $builder = $this->getBaseQuery();

    $builder->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);


    if (!empty($filter)){
        $builder->addFilter($filter);
    }

    if (!empty($sort)){
        $builder->addOrderBy($sort);
    }

    $query = $builder->getQuery();
    $query->setHydrationMode($this->getResultMode());

    $paginator = $this->getManager()->createPaginator($query);
    $totalResult = $paginator->count();
    $feedback = $paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy();



    return ['data' => $feedback , 'total' => $totalResult];
}
```

**Api result**

```
data    
0   
0   
id  1
feedback    "this shop is boring"
date    "2022-12-07T00:00:00+0100"
public  true
firstname   "some"
lastname    "thing"
total   1
success true
```

**Frontend Result**

```
0 => Array (3)
  0 => Array (4)
    id => 1
    feedback => "this shop is boring"
    date => DateTime Object (0)
    public => true
  firstname => "some"
  lastname => "thing"
  total => 1
->nocache = null
```

Comment: This looks like just two different ways of formatting the same results. It's not entirely clear what you're using to view each one

Comment: @ADyson I thought so as well, but where? cause I cant see it , doesnt my Api and my frontend method do the same thing?

Comment: I think so, I'm not a shopware user though specifically. But as I alluded to above, what tools are you using to actually visualise the data on screen? What you've shown us stops at the point you return some data from the controllers. There must be another step somewhere which turns that into visual output - presumably in the views. Maybe they do things differently. Also, are you looking at them both in a browser, or using something else? Normmally an API is designed to be used by a non-browser client...people often test them using tools such as PostMan (or similar).

Comment: I am using Postman to call my Api Controller and using the browser to get the frontend Controller, does make make a difference if I call Api through the browser? no I am only calling it through my smarty template ```$this->View()->assign('feedback', $feedback);``` and this is how I assign the variable. there is nothing more to it.

Comment: But what does the template actually do with the data? Postman will likely show the raw response returned by the API (if it's JSON or XML data, it might format it nicely for you first) whereas the template may execute more code to display it in a certain way. e.g. your front-end result looks like it might be the result of a print_r debug command, or something similar, being used on a PHP array

Comment: The template is calling the data here is a snippet of what I have in my template `{$feedbacks.customer.firstname} {$feedbacks.feedback} {$feedbacks->date.date} ` ( I am using Smarty as Template). yes my Frontend result is a debug command result, is this a problem?

Comment: Define "problem". But yeah it means you'll probably see a slightly different output. In terms of your original question, this means your API & controller code are fine, you're just seeing a difference due to the way you're outputting and viewing the data later on. P.S. `{$feedbacks.customer.firstname} {$feedbacks.feedback} {$feedbacks->date.date}` won't produce what you've posted above as far as I can see ...when you say it's from a debug command, what command is that? I assume that's something extra in your frontend view code?

Comment: I am using smarty and in Smarty there is a normal debug command `{debug}`  this will produce a Smarty Debug Console(SDC) that show all stored variables in the template I am calling I also learned how to use the PHPStorm debugger and used it to get a look of whats inside my query and it showed me the same result as the one in the Frontend but I also got to see that my `class DateTime object (0)` has values inside it such as `date`  that I am trying to retrieve so I am not sure how to get access to `date` inside my `class DateTime object (0)` and what the `(0)` in my `class DatTime object` means

Comment: `DateTime Object (0)` means there's a PHP object in there, of type DateTime, and the debugger has decided not to dump out that entire object and all its properties etc.

Comment: If it's a standard PHP DateTIme object, then all its functions and properties etc are [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How I fixed my Problem and what it was:**

With the help of @ADyson I found out what the problem was. I was tackling the problem from the wrong way though I didn't need to convert my `DateTime` to string neither in my `Model`, in my `Controller` or my `Query-builder` the only problem was the way I was calling it, there is a way of calling date objects like this in smarty and its by using `|date:'dd.MM.y'` in my case it was `{$feedbacks.date|date:'dd.MM.y'}` this get the date inside of the class and converts it to a string at the same time and like that I got to call the date that I want.

**To answer my Original Question:**

Api and Frontend don't give different result but a different Format which is for the human eye a bit different with the use of different Tools such as PHPStorm Debugger, Postman and Smarty Debugger I got to see the different result, why I am getting these Kind of results and the data inside of the class `DateTime` in my case.

**what helped me find a solution my to problem**

1. [PHPStorm Debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html).
2. [Smarty Debugger](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/language.function.debug.tpl)
3. [Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: and yes I got rid of the nested arrays and made it return only one arrays.